# Detener JavaScript cuando no esta o sale de la ventana

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un slider con jQuery que se ejecuta incluso cuando no se esta en la ventana donde se encuentra, esto me consume recursos de procesamiento en vano.

***Script***

```
$(document).ready(
$(function() {

//configuracion
var width = 650;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 7000;
var currentSlide = 1;

//cache DOM
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
var $slides = $('.imgSlide', $slider);

var interval;

function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
            if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
}
function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$slideContainer
    .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
    .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();


})
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes detectar cuando el documento actual está activo por medio de la [API de Visiblidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FUsing_the_Page_Visibility_API). Para detectar si el documento está activo basta con hacer esto:

```
if(!document.hidden) {
     // parar la ejecución de scripts, etc.
}
```

También es posible añadir un listener a la visibilidad del documento, de tal manera que detecte cuando se ha cambiado/regresado de tab.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', onVisibilityChange, false);

function onVisiblityChange(e) {
    if(document.hidden) {
        pauseSlider();
    } else {
        startSlider();
    }
}
```

---

#### Compatibilidad

- Chrome 33+
- Firefox 18+
- IE 10+
- Opera 12
- Safari 7+

Answer (score 1):

La solución esta en validar si existe o no el slider. Ya que sabes que el slider lo podes identificar con `#slider`, lo que queda es tan simple como agregar la siguiente condición en tu código

```
if($('#slider').length > 0) {

}
```

Por lo cual, te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#slider').length > 0) {
        //configuracion
        var width = 650;
        var animationSpeed = 1000;
        var pause = 7000;
        var currentSlide = 1;

        //cache DOM
        var $slider = $('#slider');
        var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
        var $slides = $('.imgSlide', $slider);

        var interval;

        function startSlider() {
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                $slideContainer.animate({
                    'margin-left': '-=' + width
                }, animationSpeed, function() {
                    if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                        currentSlide = 1;
                        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                    }
                });
            }, pause);
        }

        function pauseSlider() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        $slideContainer
          .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
          .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

        startSlider();

    }
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una opción diferente a las que te han proporcionado en otras respuestas podría ser usando la función requestAnimationFrame de javascript, la cual te permite ejecutar (digamos que) "recursivamente" el código que necesites ejecutar:

```
animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // Aqui iría el código que quieres que se ejecute iteradamente...
}
```

requestAnimationFrame retorna un identificador por cada llamado, el cual puedes usar para detener la ejecución del código en el momento en el que lo necesites:

```
var requestID;
animate();

function animate() {
  requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // El código que quieras ejecutar iteradamente iría aquí.
}

$('#stop').click(function() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
});
```

El problema del código anterior es que no se está controlando cada cuánto tiempo se va a ejecutar el código. Lo único que necesitarías hacer sería "emular" el comportamiento de setTimeout o setInterval.
A continuación te presento un ejemplo funcional de como se haría:

Nota: [Aquí](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) puedes encontrar información sobre el soporte que tiene requestAnimationFrame en los diferentes navegadores.

```js
(function() {
  var requestID;
  var i = 0;
  var last;
  var interval = 2000; // Intervalo en milisegundos
  animate();

  function animate() {
    requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if (canExecuteCode()) {
      // El código que quieres ejecutar:
      var node = document.createElement('DIV');
      node.innerText = ++i;
      document.body.appendChild(node);
    }
  }

  function canExecuteCode() {
    if (!last) {
      last = Date.now();
      return true;
    }
    
    var now = Date.now();
    var elapsed = now - last;
    
    if (elapsed >= interval) {
      last = now;
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (requestID) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
      requestID = undefined;
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('continue').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!requestID) animate();
  });
})();
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="stop">Stop!</button>
  <button id="continue">Continue</button>
</body>
```