Cambiar setInterval por setTimeout en Carousel Jquery
he tomado prestado un carousel en Jquery pero no me funciona correctamente. Al abrir otra ventana y quedarse esta de fondo pierde la sincronización. Me gusaría poder cambiar setInterval por setTimeout pues he leido que es más preciso y quizás podría reparar este bug.
Las imágenes del carousel se intercambian una a una, por medio de superposición (zIndex), con un efecto de fadeIn-fadeOut. El objeto Carousel es configurable en el número de Items(responsive), el tiempo de retraso de la animación entre cada imágen y la duración del efecto.
Aqui os dejo el código:
         (function ($) {
            //Which slot is going to be replaced next.
            var nextChangeIndex;

            //Which item is going to enter next.
            var nextItem;

            //Number of items
            var itemCount;

            //Contain the currently visible elements on screen.
            var slots;

            //Width of each item
            var itemWidth;

            //The actual carousel object
            var carousel;

            //Plugin Configuration
            var settings;

            //Currently detected screen size
            var currentBreakpoint = 0;

            //The interval timer
            var timer;

            //Swap a slot with a new item
            var swapNext = function (carousel) {
                nextChangeIndex %= settings.items; // Set the nextChangeIndex to 0 when it passes visible number of items.
                nextItem %= itemCount;

                var newItem = carousel.find(settings.itemSelector).eq(nextItem);
                slots[nextChangeIndex].fadeOut(settings.duration);
                newItem
                    .css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: 0,
                        left: (100 / settings.items) * nextChangeIndex + "%",
                        width: itemWidth,
                        zIndex: 1,
                    })
                    .fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration, function () {
                        newItem.css("z-index", 0);
                        slots[nextChangeIndex] = newItem;
                        nextChangeIndex++;
                        nextItem++;
                    });
            };

            //Calculate and initialize variable
            var setData = function () {
                nextItem = settings.items;
                itemCount = carousel.find(settings.itemSelector).length;
                itemWidth = 100 / settings.items + "%";
                slots = [];
                nextChangeIndex = 0;
            };

            //Start/restart the carousel
            var startCarousel = function () {
                carousel.css("position", "relative");
                carousel.find(settings.itemSelector).hide();
                for (var i = 0; i < settings.items; i++) {
                    slots.push(
                        carousel
                            .find(settings.itemSelector)
                            .eq(i)
                            .show()
                            .css({
                                position: "absolute",
                                top: 0,
                                left: (100 / settings.items) * i + "%",
                                width: itemWidth,
                                zIndex: 1,
                            })
                    );
                }

                if (itemCount <= settings.items) return;

                clearInterval(timer);

                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    swapNext(carousel, settings);
                }, settings.delay);
            };

            $.fn.fadeCarousel = function (options) {
                //Set the default settings
                options = $.extend(
                    {
                        items: 3,
                        delay: 4000,
                        fadeDuration: 2000,
                        itemSelector: ".fade-item",
                        responsive: {},
                    },
                    options
                );
                settings = $.extend({}, options);

                carousel = this;

                $(window).on("load resize", function () {
                    var minMaxWidth = 999999;
                    var r_settings = options;
                    $.each(settings.responsive, function (maxWidth, options) {
                        if ($(window).width() <= maxWidth && minMaxWidth > maxWidth) {
                            r_settings = options;
                            minMaxWidth = Math.min(minMaxWidth, maxWidth);
                        }
                    });

                    if (minMaxWidth !== currentBreakpoint) {
                        currentBreakpoint = minMaxWidth;

                        $.each(r_settings, function (key, value) {
                            settings[key] = value;
                        });

                        setData();
                        startCarousel();
                    }
                });

                return this;
            };
        })(jQuery);

Muchas gracias.

No es más preciso, son funciones con propósitos diferentes. setTimeout espera el tiempo asignado y ejecuta la función ingresada como argumento una sola vez, en cambio setInterval  ejecuta la función de manera indefinida (un loop) esperando un lapso de tiempo entre ejecuciones

Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero si que existe la posibilidad de recursión en setTimeout, haciendo que este se comporte como un Interval: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval . Bueno también he leido que al dejar la ventana oculta el navegador detiene la ejecucion del programa, asi que tendria que hacer algo para que se detenga y se reinicie el programa cuando el usuario cambie/vuelva  a la ventana.

Claro que es posible, también es posible sin usar ninguna de las 2 funciones. Pero ¿para qué? si javascript tiene setInterval. Pienso que lo mejor es que aclares el problema de fondo, tu indicas que pierde la sincronización a que te refieres con eso?. Además debes indicar que librería estas usando, la url de descarga y agregar un [MCVE] esto es un ejemplo reproducible donde se aprecie el problema que describes y en donde el código sea limpio, libre de otras funcionalidades que no aportan al problema

De acuerdo. Lo tendré en cuenta para la proxima vez.

Okay. Ya pude solucionarlo :) Finalmente lo que hice fue detectar cuando el documento no esta activo y detener el carrusel. Cuando el usuario vuelve a la ventana del carusel este comienza de nuevo. Aqui encontre la solucion: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23279/detener-javascript-cuando-no-esta-o-sale-de-la-ventana .
